# Why do statistical effects impact stepwise stability constants?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, kinetics, coordination-compounds, organometallic-compounds

I have a question regarding the stepwise stability constants of metal complex formation/substitution.

My lecture notes say that if we have a metal complex, say $\ce{[MX_{6}]}$, and a substitution reaction $\ce{[MX_{6}] + L -> [MX_{5}L]+X}$ with equilibrium constant $K_{1}$, and 5 other equilibrium constants $K_{2}$, $K_{3}$, ..., $K_{6}$ defined similarly for the successive substitutions of $\ce{L}$, then we have 
$$K_{1} < K_{2} < K_{3} < \dots < K_{6} $$

One of the reasons given for this is that there are fewer positions available for complexation of the $L$ ligand after some substitutions have been made, and thus it is less likely for the successive collisions to occur. This is described as a "statistical effect". As far as I understand it though, the proability of a successful colision for a given reaction affects its rate, but not its thermodynamic properties, like the equilibrium constant. Am I wrong in this?

If not, why does this "statistical effect" affect the values of $K_{i}$?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/112749 The equilibrium constant can be defined using the ratio of the forward and reverse rate constants for the reaction.

Comment: Important to note that ligand exchange in octahedral complexes is typically dissociative; i.e. an X leaves before an L can join. But I can’t get enough thoughts lined out to give an answer atm.